# Android navigation drawer troubles

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have attempted to create a navigation drawer by following this [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer). When I build and ran, It just crashed.
Here is my logcat:

```
at com.infintro.keondrae.everythingminecraft.FragmentNavigationDrawer.setupDrawerConfiguration(FragmentNavigationDrawer.java:63)
        at com.infintro.keondrae.everythingminecraft.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
```

From the logcat I got that there is a error on line 22 of the MainActivity and line 63 of the FragmentNavigationDrawer. Line 22 of the MainActivity is the onCreate for the layouts.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private FragmentNavigationDrawer dlDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Find our drawer view
    dlDrawer = (FragmentNavigationDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    // Setup drawer view
   **Line 22** dlDrawer.setupDrawerConfiguration((ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDrawer),
            R.layout.drawer_nav_item, R.id.flContent);
    // Add nav items
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Welcome", "Welcome Fragment", Welcome.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Blueprints", "Blueprints Fragment", Blueprints.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Chat", "Chat Fragment", Chat.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Redstone", "Redstone Fragment", Redstone.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Tutorials", "Tutorials Fragment", Tutorials.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Gameplay", "Gameplay Fragment", Gameplay.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Maps/Mods", "Maps/Mods Fragment", MapsMods.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("Wallpapers", "Wallpapers Fragment", Wallpapers.class);
    dlDrawer.addNavItem("About", "About Fragment", About.class);

    // Select default
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        dlDrawer.selectDrawerItem(0);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    if (dlDrawer.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Uncomment to hide menu items
        // menu.findItem(R.id.mi_test).setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Uncomment to inflate menu items to Action Bar
    // inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (dlDrawer.getDrawerToggle().onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    dlDrawer.getDrawerToggle().syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    dlDrawer.getDrawerToggle().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

FragmentNavigationDrawer.java 
 This is some of it. Line 63 is the  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

```
 // setupDrawerConfiguration((ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDrawer), R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.flContent);
public void setupDrawerConfiguration(ListView drawerListView, int drawerItemRes, int drawerContainerRes) {
    // Setup navigation items array
    drawerNavItems = new ArrayList<FragmentNavigationDrawer.FragmentNavItem>();
    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), drawerItemRes, new ArrayList<String>());
    this.drawerContainerRes = drawerContainerRes;
    // Setup drawer list view and related adapter
    lvDrawer = drawerListView;
    lvDrawer.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
    // Setup item listener
    lvDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new FragmentDrawerItemListener());
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // Setup action buttons
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 **Line 63**   getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

The layouts:

activity_main

```
<com.infintro.keondrae.everythingminecraft.FragmentNavigationDrawer
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
          android:layout_width="240dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp"
          android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    />
```

drawer_nav_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:paddingLeft="16dp"
      android:paddingRight="16dp"
      android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:textColor="#111" />
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you are using this line " drawerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), drawerItemRes, new ArrayList<String>()); " inside  this "setupDrawerConfiguration" method but in github file it is in "addNavItem" this method. So, put in this method and try again, may it works.

Comment: @SurenderKumar Thank you, but I tried to moved them to the "addNavItem" method that is under, but still crashes.

Comment: You can use this link for navigation drawer if you want - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/